# Using ADO versus stored procedure for Create and Update

Tags: stored-procedures, asp-classic, ado

Using ADO versus stored procedure for Create and Update

I am using Classic ASP, SQL server 2008 R2. I have been using ADO like this to do create and updates:

```
sSQL = "select <column list> from <table>"

set rsMyTable = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
rsMyTable.cursorType = 2 
sMyTable.LockType = 3 
rsMyTable.open sqlstr, objMyConnection     
rsMyTable.addnew

rsMyTable("Mycol1") = myValue1
rsMyTable("Mycol2") = myValue2
rsMyTable.update
rsMyTable.close
set rsMyTable = nothing
```

I have several tables that need to be updated and each update updates different sets of columns. Is it a bad practice to use ADO like this? Instead of using ADO, should I create stored procedures for each update and pass parameters to the stored procedure using ADO like this:

```
sqlstr = "myUpdateProcedure"
set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
set objParam = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")

set objCmd.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCmd.commandText = sqlstr
objCmd.CommandType = 4   ''stored proc.

set objParam = objCmd.CreateParameter("param1", 19, 1, , value1)
objCmd.Parameters.Append objParam
set objParam = objCmd.CreateParameter("param2", 200, 1, <maxlength>, value2)
objCmd.Parameters.Append objParam
....
set rsTemp = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsTemp.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rsTemp.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
set rsTemp = objCmd.Execute()

....

''cleanup.
set objParam = Nothing
set objCmd = Nothing
Set rsTemp = Nothing
```

I appreciate any advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure to perform all the updates.  You can then use transactions to ensure that all updates are performed or rolled back.  In other words move the logic you currently have in VBScript to T-SQL.

Using ADO in this way is arcahic at best and performs poorly.

If you have a lot of parameters to pass or multiple rows to update consider using XML as transport into the stored procedure.